# How to add seconds to org-mode timestamp

Tags: emacs, org-mode, time-format

I added this to .emacs:

```
(setq org-support-shift-select t)
```

So, each time a TODO item is set to done, I get this:

```
* DONE Important task
  CLOSED: [2014-09-04 Thu 18:44]
```

Is it possible to add seconds to the timestamp? So I could get this:

```
* DONE Important task
  CLOSED: [2014-09-04 Thu 18:44:31]
```

[This page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Custom-time-format.html#Custom-time-format) says, that I can customize the timestamp format. But I couldn't understand, how to do it. I tried this:

```
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%m/%d/%y %a>" "<%m/%d/%y %a %H:%M:%S>"))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(setq org-time-stamp-formats
      '("<%Y-%m-%d %a>" . "<%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S>"))
```

Take note that it's defined as a constant, so you're not encouraged to
fiddle with it (but you still can:).